# Installing .tar.bz2 format games

Tags: games, file-format

I have downloaded a game called redeclipse from their own website. It's an open source project and hopefully supports Linux too, so I have downloaded it but it came in a .tar.bz2 format.

I extracted it and it consist of several folders. I don't know how to install them from here. I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Improved my answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is no installation, unless you want to compile the game yourself. If so, give me a comment.

1. Install some dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git curl libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-image1.2
   ```
2. [Download](http://redeclipse.net/download/linux) the Linux archive
3. Open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Extract the archive (the version number `1.5.3` depends on the downloaded version)

   ```
   sudo tar xvf ~/Downloads/redeclipse_1.5.3_nix.tar.bz2 -C /opt
   ```
5. See if it works (the version number `1.5.3` depends on the downloaded version)

   ```
   /opt/redeclipse_1.5.3/redeclipse.sh
   ```
6. Create a desktop file

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/redeclipse.desktop &
   ```

   and add the content below.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Red Eclipse
   Comment=Red Eclipse
   Type=Application
   Exec=/opt/redeclipse-1.5.3/redeclipse.sh
   Icon=/opt/redeclipse-1.5.3/src/install/nix/redeclipse_x128.png
   Categories=Games;
   Terminal=false
   StartupNotify=true
   ```
7. Save and close your editor
8. Start Red Eclipse via your Dash/GNOME Shell

Comment: I tried to run the terminal command after extracting the file in home folder but it says there is no such file or directory.

Comment: I would have used /opt for the installation and not the users home.

Comment: @Rinzwind You're right. changed.